# pandas multi-group apply() change view value

Tags: python, pandas

For some reason this is not working:

sample data:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'sid':['a']*9 + ['b']*9 + ['c']*9,
                   'src': [1] *18 + [2] * 9,
                   'val':np.random.randn(27),
                    'dval': [0]*18 + np.random.rand(9)})
```

I want to multi-group by src,sid and change a `dval` row value, for those rows that are c, based on some `val` criteria.

I keep getting a `StopIteration` error.

```
# -- set bycp threshold for probability val to alert
    def quantg(g):
        try:

            g['dval'] = g['dval'].apply(lambda x: x > x['val'].quantile(.90) and 1 or 0 )
            print '***** bycp ', g.head(2)
            #print 'discretize bycp ', g.head()
            return g
        except (Exception,StopIteration) as e:
            print '**bycp error\n', e
            print g.info()
            pass
```

Then I try to filter by row before the groupby:

```
d = d[d['alert_t']=='bycp'].groupby(['source','subject_id','alert_t','variable']).apply(quantg )
```

I also tried mulitlevel select:

```
 # -- xs for multilevel select
 g['dval'] = g.xs(('c','sid')).map(lambda x: len(g['value']) and\
                                                             #(x>g['value'].quantile(.90) and 1 or 0 ))
```

But no luck!

Get `frameindex` or `stopiteration` type errors.

what gives, how can i get this done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following doesn't do what you think it does:

```
x > x['val'].quantile(.90) and 1 or 0
```

*Ifn fact, if you try it with a Series it ought to raise a ValueError.*

```
In [11]: dt and True
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

When writing something like that you want to use `np.where`:

```
np.where(x > x['val'].quantile(.90), 1, 0)
```

*Note: `astype('int64')` would also work, or just leaving it as bool...*

However, I think I might use a transform here (to extract each groups quantile and then mask off this), with something like:

```
q90 = g.transform(lambda x: x.quantile(.90))
df[df.val > q90]
```

Comment: how do you update multindex dataframes.  d.update(dnew) gives a valueerror, cannot reindex from duplicate axis?

Comment: @syntax not sure what the question is, could you post as a separate question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping get my head around np.where; please see my edit regarding update.  thanks again!

Comment: @syntax please can you post that as a new/separate question! Doing so allows other people to answer too, and will mean others googling the same issue in future will be able to find it more easily.

Comment: yeah no problem, (been away from my desk)... but where is the edit?